# Dividing in Python

Tags: python, divide

im new Python and I am practicing a few things but I couldnt seem to work out why the 4 grades shown below in my code wont properly divide by 4. E.g I will type all the grades as 2 and be shown 6.5 as the total grade average.

Heres the code:

```
#FinalGrade
Student = str(input("Student Name: "))
Grade1 = int(input("Enter Student's First Grade: "))
Grade2 = int(input("Enter Student's Second Grade: "))
Grade3 = int(input("Enter Student's Third Grade: "))
Grade4 = int(input("Enter Student's Fourth Grade: "))

print ("Total Grade Average: %G" % (Grade1+Grade2+Grade3+Grade4/4))

print ("%s has:" % (Student))

if Grade1+Grade2+Grade3+Grade4/4 < 40:
print ("Failed!")
if Grade1+Grade2+Grade3+Grade4/4 > 40:
print ("Passed!")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
Grade1+Grade2+Grade3+Grade4/4
```

to

```
(Grade1+Grade2+Grade3+Grade4)/4
```

See the difference here:

```
>>> 1 + 2 +3 +4/4
7
>>> (1+2+3+4)/4
2
>>>
```

In the first case, the value is being evaluated as

```
Grade1+Grade2+Grade3+(Grade4/4)
```

What you want is

```
(Grade1+Grade2+Grade3+Grade4)/4
```

Consider extracting it as a local variable.

```
#FinalGrade
Student = str(input("Student Name: "))
Grade1 = int(input("Enter Student's First Grade: "))
Grade2 = int(input("Enter Student's Second Grade: "))
Grade3 = int(input("Enter Student's Third Grade: "))
Grade4 = int(input("Enter Student's Fourth Grade: "))

average =  (Grade1+Grade2+Grade3+Grade4 )/4
print ("Total Grade Average: %G" % (average))

print ("%s has:" % (Student))

if average < 40:
    print ("Failed!")
if average > 40:
    print ("Passed!")

#what if average == 40 ?
```

To enter everything on the same line,

```
passed_or_failed = "Passed"
if average < 40:
    passed_or_failed = 'Failed'

print ("%s has: %s" % (Student, passed_or_failed))
```

Comment: Thank you very much :) Do you know how to get the "Passed" / "Failed" to appear on the same line as the 'student has:' line?

Comment: Sorry, should have seen that!

Answer (score 3):

It's not python.  You need to understand the rules of precedence for Math operators.

You're only dividing Grade4 by 4, and not the sum of the grades.

Answer (score 1):

Because of [order of operations](http://www.mathcs.emory.edu/~valerie/courses/fall10/155/resources/op_precedence.html), what's actually being evaluated is

```
Grade1 + Grade2 + Grade3 + (Grade4 / 4)
```

To fix this, use parentheses around the grades or sum them separately:

```
gradeAvg = (Grade1 + Grade2 + Grade3 + Grade4) / 4

gradeSum = Grade1 + Grade2 + Grade3 + Grade4
gradeAvg = gradeSum / 4
```

Comment: Thank you so much, wow am I stupid for missing this!

Answer (score 1):

```
if (Grade1+Grade2+Grade3+Grade4)/4 < 40:
```